# Convert Local Time as string to milliseconds from 1jan1970

Tags: c, time, embedded, stm32

I have this string that gives me the current time in `ddmmyyhhmmss:sss` which is equivalent to an `uint8_t array[8];` like,

```
array[0] = date;
array[1] = month;
array[2] = year;    //13
array[3] = hours;
array[4] = minutes;
array[5] = seconds;
array[6-7] = milliseconds;
```

All I want is to get the time difference from midnight 1 Jan 1970 to current time in milliseconds, in a `uint64_t` variable.

Can I do this? -->
tm1 structure = 1 jan 1970 midnight
tm2 structure = current time from array[].

```
time1 = mktime(tm1);
time2 = mktime(tm2);
Difference = time1-time2;   //in milliseconds, if not then multiply by 1000
```

Comment: If your system have it, then you could use [`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime). If not then search for an implementation of it.

Comment: I dont want to use `<time.h>`, Need an own function.

Comment: Then it's *much* harder.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok now I can use `<time.h>`. I have edited the question, please tell if I can do like this?

Comment: Well if the epoch of your system already is  1 Jan 1970, then you don't need to do anything other than calling `mktime`, as that then will return the number of seconds since then. Just multiply by 1000 and you have your time.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg It's not that hard. Use a table for months and figure out how to do leap years correctly, plus some multiplications.

Comment: @starblue can you provide some code? basically like a while loop, then check year==leap, then add number of days 366 else add number of days 365.

Comment: @starblue That's the simple part. The hard part comes with time-zones, daylight saving and leap seconds.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg That's true, though most of the time you can ignore leap seconds (Unix time uses UTC, not TAI).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes! that would be very hard, even after ignoring leap seconds, I have got the answer with mktime.

Comment: Is your `1 Jan 1970` local time or UTC time?

Comment: @chux It is Local time.

Comment: Consider posting what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Time.h works in 1 second increments, and needs a 32-bit value designate time_t **time** as a count of seconds since 01/01/1970.

You need a real-time clock to generate an interrupt every second and the ISR needs to increment **time**.  You need some means of initialising **time**. You can then derive the current time and date in various formats from **time** using the functions in time.h.

If your system also has a 1KHz interrupt clock you can create another variable int **ms**, and increment it from the 1KHz ISR.  The RTC ISR should reset **ms** to zero.  The current time can then be deduced by concatenating **time** and **ms**.  Midnight on the morning of 01/01/1970 was the time when both **time** and **ms** were zero.